# Why would someone design a RESTful API with 'API' in the URI?

Tags: web-services, rest, scalability, uri, api-design

I just finished reading [Restful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260) and [Nobody Understands REST or HTTP](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/2011/07/03/nobody-understands-rest-or-http.html) and am trying to design an API with a RESTful design.

I've noticed a few patterns in API URI design:

```
http://api.example.com/users
http://example.com/api/users
http://example.com/users
```

Assume that these designs properly use `Accept` and `Content-type` headers for [content negotiations](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html) between XHTML, JSON, or any format.

> Are these URI's a matter of a *pure* RESTful implementation vs implicit content negotiation?

My thoughts are that by explicitly using API in the URI is so that a client will expect a data format that is not inherently human pleasing hypermedia and can be more easily consumed without explicitly setting an `Accept` header. In other words, the API is implying that you expect JSON or XML rather than XHTML.

> Is this a matter of separating resource representations
>   logically on the server side?

The only justification I can come up with for why someone would design their URI's with an API subdomain is because, based off my assumption that this is a scaling technique, it should make routing request load easier in a multi-tiered server infrastructure. Maybe situations exist where reverse proxies are stripping the headers? I don't know. Different servers handling different representations?

Maybe a subdomain is used for external consumers only so that the server avoids the overhead from internal usage. Rate limiting?

> Am I missing a point?

My proposed design would attempt to follow RESTful practices by setting appropriate headers, using HTTP verbs appropriately and representing resources in a fashion that I feel including 'API' in the URI would be redundant.

> Why would someone design a RESTful API with 'API' in the URI?

Or could they? Maybe my problem with not understanding this design is that *it doesn't matter* as long as it follows some combination of specification which may not lead to a RESTful API implementation but close? *There is more than one way to skin a keyboard cat.*
[HATEOAS](http://timelessrepo.com/haters-gonna-hateoas) related?

---

**Update:** While researching this topic I have come to the conclusion that it's important to consider ideas from REST but not to treat it as a religion. Thus, whether or not to have 'api' in the URI is more of a design decision than a steadfast rule. If you plan to expose your website's API publicly it would be a good idea to use an api subdomain to help deal with the application's logic. I hope that someone will contribute their insight for others to learn from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my understanding and point of view about your question :

> Are these URI's a matter of a pure RESTful implementation vs implicit
>   content negotiation?

No, they are not part of any official documentation (that I know of), and are usually at the developper/team standards discretion. For example, [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) uses some utility classes to detect XHR requests and how responses should be returned. Granted, ZF is not pure RESTful design (or most PHP application as a matter of fact), but it is still possible to write such designs even in PHP.

I have often seen `api` being used in urls when the returned data expected is indeed not meant to be used as is for display to the end user. However it is usually a design decision and not necessarily an implied standard.

> Is this a matter of separating resource representations logically on
>   the server side?

More or less. For example, when performing a `PUT` request, for example, the interface does not necessarily need to be entirely refreshed, and often a simple response message is good enough. While this response message is part of the view, it is not *the* view. So, for example, `http://domay.com/users/` would return the interface to manage users (or whatever), `http://domain.com/users/api` would perform operations and return interface updates (without a page reload).

> Am I missing a point?

Weell, no. Since it is a design decision to use or not `api` in the URL, you're not missing anything here. With the proper headers,

```
http://domain.com/users/api/get
http://domain.com/users/get
http://domain.com/users/
```

can all be valid RESTful requests.

> Why would someone design a RESTful API with 'API' in the URI?

Simply put, to have an URL naming convention. So that, when looking at a request in logs, documentation, etc. One will understand it's purpose.

Answer (score 11):

I would (and have) done it to separate it from the 'website' infrastructure because it's probably going to have a higher load and require more infrastructure - it's a lot easier to do millions of API calls a day than get that in page views because you have the full load of n sites/companies and their efforts and traction, collectively and even in some cases individually they're going to attract more traffic than you yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Also keep in mind, that most frameworks (django, RoR,...) provide URL-based routing out of the box. You probably need different views for API vs. HTML responses to manage things like authentication, trotting, limits-check and other specific stuff differently.

Putting in place an additional HTTP-Header based routing system to allow, as you say, implicit content negotiation is often not worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

User-visible webpage URLs are subject to the whims of webmasters, designers, corporate organization, marketing, fashion, technology, etc.

An API, on the other hand, is supposed to remain stable. By using a subdomain you isolate your API from the rest of the website and the changes it is likely to undergo in time.